# How to make a .transition in Swift with value of time animation?

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-animation

I have code like this in my ContentView:

I want to make this transition slow than now, it looks like this right know, but animation is too fast. I don't know how to do it. Type of AnyTransition doesn't have something like value or duration methods.

[How it's look?: GIF from Simulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6TKuF.gif)

```
struct ContentView: View {
        
    @EnvironmentObject var session: SessionManager

    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            switch session.currentState {
            case .loggedIn:
                TabBar()
                    .transition(.move(edge: .bottom))
            case .onboardingSetup:
                OnboardingSetupView(action: session.completeOnboardingSetup)
                    .animation(.easeInOut, value: 0.5)
            case .onboarding:
                OnboardingView(action: session.completeOnboarding)
                    .transition(
                        .move(edge: .bottom)
                    )
            default:
                ProgressView()
            }
        }
        .animation(.easeInOut, value: session.currentState)
        .onAppear(perform: session.configureCurrentState)
    }
}
```

I tried to use .animation, but still i can't add duration to this code:

```
  case .onboarding:
                OnboardingView(action: session.completeOnboarding)
                    .transition(
                        .move(edge: .bottom)
                    )
```

Comment: try `.animation(.easeInOut(duration: 3), value: session.currentState)`

Comment: Thank you, it's working. What is important in my case it work on every case in session. I didn't expect it, but it has sense.